# ARM Assembler load machinecode into ram

Tags: c, assembly

i need to load a file which is a .function file from C Code into ram and run it from Assembler-Code.

how can i load this File into ram correctly so that i can jump to this function in assembler?

Comment: this is extremely system dependent, please provide more information on what you are doing, what environment, what processor, etc

Comment: Load it from where:  LAN?  Disk?  Floppy?  USB?

Comment: You should link the assembler code with the linker. You can use the function name directly from your C code.